# How to detect MacRoman encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, php-7.2, mac-roman

PHP's `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't understand the `MacRoman` encoding. My app allows users to upload data in csv format and I need to convert it to utf8 because the users are not tech-savvy. I will never be able to get all of them to understand how to do it and control their encoding.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$encoding_detection_order = array('UTF-8', 'UTF-7', 'ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'EUC-JP', 'SJIS', 'eucJP-win', 'SJIS-win', 'JIS', 'ISO-2022-JP', );

$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, $detection_order, true);

$converted_value = iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $value);
```

This works great for most situations, but if my user is on a Mac and they save the CSV in `MacRoman` encoding, then the above code will usually wrongly detect the text as `ISO-8859-1` which causes the `iconv()` to produce bad output.

For example, the accented-e in `Jaimé` has a hex value of `0x8e` in `MacRoman`. In `ISO-8859-1`, the `0x8e` character is `Ž` and so when I covert it to utf8, I just get the utf8 version of `Ž` when I should be getting `é`.

[image]

I need to be able to dynamically differentiate `MacRoman` from other encodings so that I convert it properly.

Comment: Also interested in a solution as is it is also used in some pdfencoding (p. 550 of pdf specs : [https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.3.pdf](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.3.pdf))